# I've found a Json data using findById, how do I use it in my code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, loopback

I am creating an API that gets Patients data(id and name), Physicians data(id and name) and Appointments(id, phyId, patId, app_date) and displays the Patients appointed to a particular physician. I need to create a remote method in physician.js in such a way that I get related Appointment that has phyId and print the details of the Patients using the patId obtained from appointment.
I'm using loopback 3.

Refer this link for clear idea:

https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/HasManyThrough-relations.html

I have related models (Physicians, Patients) that are related by "hasMany" with each other "through" Appointment(another model) and Appointment is related to each of these by belongsTo, in my loopback application and i need to print the Patients of a particular Physician.

Patient data:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Anna Mull"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Paige Trner"
  }
]
```

Physician data:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Cardiologist"
  }
]
```

Appointment data:

```
 [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "physicianId": 1,
    "patientId": 1,
    "appointmentDate": "2019-01-28T10:06:33.530Z"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "physicianId": 1,
    "patientId": 2,
    "appointmentDate": "2019-01-28T10:06:33.530Z"
  }
 ]
```

I know there is a method already available to query the Patients of a Physician, but I want to code it myself to learn and also print it in the following format.
My idea is to get all the Appointments having the specific phyId in it and find the patId in those appointment and store it in an array. I then use that array to get the patients from the Patient model. I managed to get the Patient details in a function, but I can only console.log(Patients) but I am not able to display it in the API response.

The following is the format i need it in. (EXPECTED OUTPUT in API response)

```
Physician:

{

   "id": 1,

   "name": "Cardiologist"
}

Patients:

[
    {

    "id": 1,

    "name": "Anna Mull"

    },

    {

    "id": 2,

    "name": "Paige Trner"

    }
]
```

or any similar format.

I've tried to the same and here is my code.

common/models/physician.js

```
'use strict';
var app = require('../../server/server');
module.exports = function (Physician) {

Physician.getDetails = function (phyid, cb) {

    var Appointments = app.models.Appointment;

    var Patient = app.models.Patient;

    Physician.findById(phyid, function (err, Physician) {

        Appointments.find({ where: { physicianId: phyid } }, function (err, Appointment) {
            if (err) {

                cb(null, "Errorrrrrrrr", "Errorrrrrr");

            }

            else {

                var patients = [], i = 0;

                var patobj= [];

                for (i in Appointment) {

                    patients[i] = Appointment[i].patientId;

                    //console.log(patients);

                Patient.findById(patients[i], function(err, Patients){

                    if(err){

                        cb("Error in patients", "--");

                    }

                    else{

                        patobj[i]=Patients;//doesnt have any effect

                        console.log(Patients);//prints in console

                    }

                });

            }

                cb(null, Physician, patobj);//only Physician is printed, patobj is empty.


            }
        });

    });

}


Physician.remoteMethod('getDetails', {
    http: {
        path:
            '/:phyid/getDetails',
        verb: 'get'
    },
    accepts: {
        arg: 'phyid',
        type: 'number'
    },
    returns: [{
        arg: 'Physician',
        type: 'Object'
    }, {
        arg: 'Patient',
        type: 'Object'
    }]

});

};
```

I am actually getting this in the API response:

```
 {

    "Physician": {

    "id": 1,

    "name": "Cardiologist"

     },

    "Patient": []

 }
```

and this in the console:

D:\Project\Project1>node .

Web server listening at: http://localhost:3000

Browse your REST API at http://localhost:3000/explorer

{ name: 'Anna Mull', id: 1 }

{ name: 'Paige Trner', id: 2 }

How am I supposed to get the patient data to be printed in the API response?

Answer (score 0):

You patients are empty because, finding Patients by Id is an asynchronous operation. But the `for` loop is synchronous. The loop finishes and calls the following line before any of the Patients are found.

```
cb(null, Physician, patobj);//only Physician is printed, patobj is empty.
```

You need to wait for all the patients to be found by using either [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) or [async.each](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each).

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining it. I'm totally new to this type of coding and thanks for your time. I'll work it out and let you know if it worked.